# Inputbinding - Delay Between Mouse Clicks, EventToCommand Works Fine

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm-light, inputbinding

Up until today I've been using MVVM Light's EventToCommand for event handling in XAML. I decided to try out InputBinding for mouse events and so far the results have been far from pleasing. I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong because there's a delay of maybe half a second between mouse clicks. With EventToCommand, the UI will update as fast as I can click it. All this test program does at the moment is fills a circle on a canvas either white or black when it's clicked.

```
<Canvas>
    <Ellipse Canvas.Left="{Binding X}"
        Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}"
        Width="16"
        Height="16"
        Fill="Black">
        <Ellipse.InputBindings>
            <MouseBinding Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                                Path=DataContext.ClickEllipse}"
                       CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                AncestorType={x:Type Ellipse}}}"
                       MouseAction="LeftClick" />
</Ellipse.InputBindings>
```

```
public RelayCommand<object> ClickEllipse { get; set; }
ClickEllipse = new RelayCommand<object>((o) => ExecuteClickEllipse(o));

private void ExecuteClickEllipse(object o)
    {
        var obj = o as Ellipse;

        if (obj.Fill == Brushes.Black)
        {
            obj.Fill = Brushes.White;
            TestText = "White";
        }
        else
        {
            obj.Fill = Brushes.Black;
            TestText = "Black";
        }
    }
```

What am I doing anything wrong here to cause the delay between clicks? I can't imagine that this would be the intended behavior. I have EventToCommand set up almost identically and it has no problems. Furthermore, assuming I did make a stupid mistake and this isn't intended behavior, are there any advantages of InputBinding over EventToCommand for Key and Mouse events or vice versa? How do the 2 differ in terms of functionality and performance (if that's even an issue in this situation)?

Edit - Something else I've noticed with both InputBinding and EventToCommand (which I have set up almost identically) is that each time the circle is clicked, task manager shows the program's memory usage jumping up a bit. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just been looking into your problem... now I don't use that `RelayCommand`, instead preferring my own `ActionCommand`, but I've looked at the code for it and they are practically the same. So, I added your code to a new WPF applicaton and here's what I found:

When I click on the circle, it *immediately* changes colour. If I click on it again, it *immediately* changes colour again. However, if I double click on the circle, it only changes colour once and I would have expected it to change colour twice. Clicking on it multiple times makes it alternate between white and black, but only at a rate of about two per second... *much* slower than the rate of clicks.

Changing the `Ellipse` to a `TextBlock` and updating the `Text` property in the click handler had similar results. However, when I replace the `MouseBinding` with a simple event handler for the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event, this 'slow reaction time' disappears.

Continuing my testing, I then added a `Button` and set the *same* `Command` on its `Command` property (after removing it from the `TextBlock`). This just used my `ActionCommand` and it worked immediately and perfectly on every click.

So it appears that there *is* indeed a delay between *multiple* invocations of the *same* function when using this method of routing `Command`s through a `MouseBinding`. While this answer may not help you, I hope at least that this confirmation of the problem will help in some small way.

Regarding the memory issue, I wouldn't worry about that. WPF is often quick to ask for memory and slow to let it go.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough response. The information you found is certainly helpful and I really do appreciate the time and effort that you put into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a workaround.

The "MouseAction" does not register a second click because the WPF thinks it's a double click.

So by adding a second "MouseAction" on double click shout fix this problem.

Add this code under your mouse binding.

```
<MouseBinding Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},
                            Path=DataContext.ClickEllipse}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType={x:Type Ellipse}}}"
                            MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" />
```

I know it is a dirty solution, but I haven't found a better one yet.